# Question about radians.

Tags: geometry

I just started learning about radians and encountered a very simple question.

> A person can read print at such a distance that the letters sugtend an angle of $5'$ at his eye. Find what is the height of the letters that he can read at a distance of 12 meters?

What is meant by "height of the letters" in the question?
I checked the solution of the question and it says:

> Let $h$ be the required height in metres. Here $h$ can be considered as the arc of a circle of radius $12$ m which subtends an angle of $5'$ at its center.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height of the letters in this case is the length of the [chord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_%28geometry%29) where the ends of the chord form the line segment going to the endpoints of  the [arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_%28geometry%29) of the circle of radius 12 subtending angle 5'. The reason why copper.hat's approximation is so very good is due to the [small angle approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation#Geometric). In other words, 5' is so negligible that the length of the leg of the right triangle opposite angle the angle 5' is [very nearly the chord](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4b/Small_angle_triangle.svg) on the ray.

This chord is how your eyeballs actually see things, but it is appropriate to apply trigonometry as copper has done for such small angles as the math is so much simpler, and the approximate difference in results is so negligible. Note that the actual length of this chord will be negligibly smaller than the height of the leg opposing 5' angle on right triangle with other leg 12. You might want to apply some result related to geometry on a ray.

Comment: Does the height refer to the height of letters above the page or does if refers to how far do the letters stretch?

Comment: How far the letters stretch, and so you can think of the height of the letter as just a vertical line corresponding to the chord length.

Comment: So why would the question call it height?

Comment: Well we're just making an analog between the height of the letter and the length of a chord. The periphery that your eyeball can see is effectively a chord like this.

Comment: So height here refers to how tall any letter is.

Comment: Yes, and precisely. In fact I think you just consolidated this entire thought/question into one sentence better than anyone could ever do. I am happily laughing with satisfaction. Why did it not occur to me to post that as an answer?!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$h = 12 \tan 5' \approx 0.0175$m (that is, about 17.5 mm).

Comment: what does height of letters mean in the question?Btw Your answer is correct.

Comment: It is a little ambiguous, however, for small angles $\tan \theta \approx \theta$ (with $\theta $ in radians), so $12 ({5 \over 60} {\pi \over 180}) \approx 12 \tan 5'$.

Comment: I am asking about the meaning of "height of letters" in the question.

Comment: It is ambiguous. One imagines that the letters are at least printed on flat paper, so the answer suggestion of an arc is an approximation. One could ask what is the smallest height of a letter on flat paper that can be read at 12m in optimal conditions, in which case I would answer $h = 12 \cdot 2 \tan {5' \over 2} \approx 17.5$mm (that is, essentially the same as the answer above).